# Java : Removing First three characters from a String

Tags: java

I am getting a String value as

```
String A = KS!BACJ
String B = KS!KLO
String C = KS!MHJU
String D = KS!GHHHY
```

Is it possible to remove the KS! from the String so that it only looks like  BACJ

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
     String A = "KS!BACJ";
     if(A.startsWith("KS!"))
     {
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, did you even begin to try to figure this out? Do you do the *slightest* search? Glance fleetingly at the API documentation of the JDK?

Comment: This is a simple solution, if you have searched API documentation or even in autosuggest feature of eclipse (if your ide is eclipse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `String a = A.substring(3);`

Comment: Note: It does NOT "remove the first three charaters from a string" - it creates a new string without the first three characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new string by using [`String#substring(int idx)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

In your case it is `yourString.substring(3)`, which will return a string without the first three characters, e.g.:

```
String newString = yourString.substring(3);
```

**Note:** We cannot "Remove First three characters from a String" (not easily at least) because `String` is *immutable* - but we can create a new string without the first 3 characters.

---

**Bonus:**

To "Remove the first characters from a String" - you are going to need to work hard and use reflection. 

**This is not advised to ever be used**, here for educational purposes alone!

```
String A = "KS!BACJ";
Field offset = A.getClass().getDeclaredField("offset");
offset.setAccessible(true);
offset.set(A, (Integer)offset.get(A) + 3);
Field count = A.getClass().getDeclaredField("count");
count.setAccessible(true);
count.set(A, A.length()-3);
System.out.println(A);
```

Comment: This looks like the more detailled answer to me. +1

Comment: I fixed the worst of the problems with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String.substring(String.indexOf("!")+1 , String.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

With Apache commmons-lang [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#removeStart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String aString = "KS!BACJ";
String bString = StringUtils.removeStart("KS!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder instead. It does not make a new `String` object. It just deletes the first 3 letters or more from the given string.

```
String st = "HELLO";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(st);
str.delete(0, 3);
Log.d("str", str.toString());
```

Output:

> LO

Comment: *"It does not make a new `String` object"*  Until you call `.toString()`, at which point it does...